# Difference between android:layout_alignParentTop and android:layout_alignParentStart

Tags: android, android-layout

The documentation says:

> android:layout_alignParentStart
>
> If true, makes the start edge of this view match the start edge of the parent.

and

> android:layout_alignParentTop
>
> If true, makes the top edge of this view match the top edge of the parent.

So what's the difference between start edge and top edge?

I'm sorry if this question is already answered, I just couldn't find it. Blame my poor Googling skills.

Comment: Top is literally that - the top edge of the screen. Start (and End) to my knowledge are left and right positions. On a device where language / locale preference is left-to-right then Start will be left edge of the screen but if the preference is right-to-left then Start will be the right edge of the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know `Layout` attributes ending with "Start" are used to match the start of content direction like supporting RTL texts where the start of the `View` is not the default.

Comment: "RTL" means "Right to Left", which is for example needed for the Arabian language?

Answer (score 0):

Native support of Right-to-Left (RTL) languages was introduced in Android v4.2 (Jelly Bean). [Here is the official blog entry on this](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html)

To support RTL, it's advised to replace Left/Right layout properties to Start/End equivalents. Top/Bottom attributes, however, remained intact.

Please, read the blog entry for the details, there's no need to copy it here.